# How do I fix a 404 error using file_get_contents in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

When I run the following php file from a **subfolder** of htdocs, I get a 404 error: "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Let's call the subfolder "**other**".

When run the same file from htdocs folder, I get the error: "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\other\DBConnection.php on line 12 PHP."

I would like to be able to run the file successfully from the "other" folder because I will be using this to test multiple projects and websites.

I believe that the problem is that there is something missing from the file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Open+Water&y=&plot=full&r=json"); line.  ie. to tell this command to look in the htdocs folder where it will be able to access the internet or to authorize it to access the internet from the "other" file.

I have researched here and the web but cannot find the answer.  I have tried moving the connection code into the "OMDB query" file, but that produces an error similar to the 2nd error from above.  Can anyone help me fix this?

Windows 10
NetBeans 8.0.2
XAMPP
PHP 5.6.8
mySQL 5.6
Accessing OMDb.com api.

Code:

```
<?php
/*
 * File: OMDB query.php
 * Author:  Jim Stevens
 * Date: 08/14/2015
 * Description:  Imports records from OMDb and inserts results into local mySQL DB.
 */
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\other\DBConnection.php';
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Open+Water&y=&plot=full&r=json");

// Decodes .json file, creates & populates an associative array.
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

// Extracts the array data.
$title = $data['Title'];
$year = $data['Year'];
$rated = $data['Rated'];
...more fields...

// Inserts extracted values into mySQL table 'myDB'.
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies.myDB(title, yr, rated, ...more fields...')";

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
}
...
?>
```

The DBConnection.php file is store in the "other" folder.  It successfully connects to "myDB" and works as expected:

Code:

```
<?php

/*
 * File: DBConnection.php
 * Author:  Jim Stevens
 * Date: 08/09/2015
 * Description:  Creates and manages myDB database connections.
 */

require_once 'config.php'; // The file with username, password, dbname, & dbhostname.

$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die($connection->connect_error);
}

//  The following works correctly but is a leftover from initial testing and will be removed eventually.
$query = "SELECT * FROM myDB";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die($connection->error);
}
$rows = $result->num_rows;
for ($j=0; $j < $rows; ++$j) {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo 'Title: ' . $row['title'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Year: '  . $row['yr']    . '<br>';
    echo 'Rated: ' . $row['rated'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Actors: '. $row['actors']. '<br>';
    echo 'Plot: '  . $row['plot']  . '<br><br>';
}
$result->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your file_get_contents() function.

You're getting an error BEFORE the interpreter even touches this line.

As your error output said (and you really should trust it), the error is located at line 12 of your DBConnection.php file, so:

```
$connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

                  ^ here
```

You probably doesn't have Mysqli installed. Check the docs on [how to install it](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) on Windows, or check XAMPP's documentation.

Comment: Rafael, thank you for your response.  I will double-check if mysqli is installed and installed correctly.  Is there a reason why this command  (appears?) to work correctly when I run DBConnection.php by itself?

Comment: Rafael, thanks!  That solved problem #1!  Still get the same 404 error when I run "OMDb query.php" from the "other" folder, though.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I think you need to provide more info on that. What exactly the new error line says? Maybe it could be a simple file reference error. Also, avoid using whitespaces in .php filenames. Maybe you're trying to access it on a browser and it isn't finding your file, thus the 404 error.

Comment: Rafael, refactored the name to OMDb_query.php and it runs perfectly from the desired location now.  Thank you so much!